# JSON parse string?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a JSON file that contains two objects. This file is in server side.

> [ {"param1":"market"}, {"param2":"you"} ]

I want to parse these objects and set to my String param1,param2

```
private String param1 = null;
private String param2 = null;
```

I can not understand how to code. Please give me sample code for this.

Comment: @Dalton I did not know how to parse. The link you wrote who asked that question said " I have already got JSON string by code "

Answer (score 0):

```
[ {"param1":"market"}, {"param2":"you"} ]
```

The square brackets are showing that your response starts with JSON array. So, you should have key name of JSON array so that you can find the value of JSON objects from JSON array.

Comment: Can you give me sample code ? I am newbie development of android.

Comment: [JSON Parsing Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/), hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

so you need to call the server to get the jsonString you can make service call like this by passing url and getting the json str

```
public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }
```

---

then you use the jsonStr you get from the call like this.

```
String jsonStr = makeServiceCall(String reqUrl);
JSONArray jsonArr= new JSONArray(jsonStr);
JSONObject jsonObjectOne = jsonArr.getJSONObject(0);
String param1 = jsonObjectOne.getString("param1");
JSONObject jsonObjectTwo = jsonArr.getJSONObject(1);
String param2 = jsonObjectTwo.getString("param2");
```

Comment: jsonStr is in server side. I keep it in txt file. Can you modify your code ?

Comment: Edited the answer hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "[ {"param1":"market"}, {"param2":"you"} ]"

JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(string);

JSONObject firstPart = arr.getJSONObject(0);

JSONObject secondPart = arr.getJSONObject(1);

firstPart.getString("param1");
secondPart.getString("param2");
```

Comment: my objects are in server side. I keep it in txt file. Can you modify your code ?

Comment: This code seems to be a string or already an JSONArray, if it is the first, do it like the code I wrote. If it is the second case you just delete the first two lines.